# Web Service doesn't keep state between requests

Tags: php, session, asmx, session-state

I am developing an ASP.NET Web Service:

```
# MyWS.cs
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public bool TryLogin(string user, string pass)
{
    if (/* user validation is successful*/)
    {
        Context.Session["user"] = user;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Context.Session.Abandon();
        return false;
    }
}
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string RetrieveSomething()
{
    if (Context.Session["user"] == null)
        throw Exception("User hasn't logged in.");
    /* retrieve something */;
}
```

This ASP.NET must be consumed by a PHP Web site I am developing as well:

```
# ws_client.php
function get_soap_client()
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['client']))
        $_SESSION['client'] = new SoapClient('MyWS.asmx?WSDL');
    return $_SESSION['client'];
}
function try_login($user, $pass)
{
    return get_soap_client()->TryLogin(
        array('user' => $user, 'pass' => $pass))
        ->TryLoginResult;
}
function retrieve_something()
{
    return get_soap_client()->RetrieveSomething(
        array())->RetrieveSomethingResult;
}

# index.html
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        session_start();
        require_once('ws_client.php');
        if (try_login($_POST['user'],
                      $_POST['pass']))
        {
            session_write_close();
            header('Location: /main.php');
            exit();
        }
?>
<html> <!-- login form here >

# main.php
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('ws_client.php');
    // Here I get the Exception "User hasn't logged in.", even though
    // the user has logged in and the web service has already been notified.
    echo htmlspecialchars(retrieve_something());
?>
```

What could be wrong with either my Web Service or my PHP site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the PHP SOAP tools, but Session state is maintained through a cookie. Will this code accept a cookie the first time, then send it back on subsequent calls?

Comment: I don't know. How should I read the cookie on the second request (the `RequestSomething` WebMethod)?

Comment: @Eduardo: like I said, I don't know PHP.

Comment: @John: I meant to ask whether the C# Web Service is correctly processing the request.

Comment: @Eduardo: assume it does, and that there's something you have to configure with PHP. If you wonder, then look at the network traffic with Fiddler or the like, to see if the web service is sending a cookie, and if the PHP is sending it back.

Comment: @Eduardo: sorry, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) is a tool for examining and modifying HTTP and HTTPS traffic.

Comment: @John: I have just downloaded it, and it shows all traffic related to StackOverflow, but nothing related to my site. I guess I have to configure Fidller properly first.

Comment: @Eduardo: if both the web service and  your site are on the same machine, then see the FAQ on how to configure it to capture localhost traffic.